# How do make continuously running functions in MFC that don't freeze the window?

Tags: c++, mfc, cursor, infinite-loop

I am new to MFC and am making a simple program that will continuously update two edit boxes.  The edit boxes contain the x and y coordinates of the mouse cursor.  The program only starts grabbing the cursor coordinates when the start button is clicked, and it's supposed to stop when the stop button is clicked. But as soon as I click the start button the entire window freezes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
//Way up high in the code:
#include <windows.h>

//way down low in the code

void CmfcpixelDlg::OnBnClickedButtonStart()
{
POINT p;

CString x;
CString y;

int px;
int py;

while(stop == false){

    GetCursorPos(&p);

    px = p.x;
    //convert x coordinate to a CString
    x.Format(L"%d", px);
    //convert y coordinate to a CString
    py = p.y;
    y.Format(L"%d", py);
    m_x.SetWindowTextW(x.GetBuffer());
    m_y.SetWindowTextW(y.GetBuffer());


}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're blocking the event loop. You can't do a loop that requires user intervention to end in the GUI thread - you need to do it in a separate thread.

In fact, you shouldn't perform *any* lengthy operations in the main thread.

Basically, the same thread that is running your loop is the thread that is responsible for displaying and updating the GUI. Because this thread is now waiting for a GUI update to exit the loop *and* this thread is the same thread that's supposed to update the GUI, you have a Catch-22, or in programmer speak, a deadlock.

To resolve this, you can split your code off into a new thread, or better yet, design it to eliminate the loop entirely. Your code is fairly simple, and this can be done loop free:

- On click of start: set the flag.
- On mouse move: update the x, y coordinate text *if* the flag is set. No loops!
- On click of stop: unset the flag.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked quite well, the only problem now is that the cursor coordinates only display if the cursor is inside the dialod box.  Is there any way to get the coordinates no matter where the cursor is on the screen?

Comment: @xcdemon you'll have to use a timer callback or second thread to pull that off.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `OnMouseMove` event, and update the edit boxes only if the user has clicked start.

Comment: With OnMouseMove you only get moves as long as the moise pointer is inside the CmfcpixelDlg window.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, but that did not seem an issue in OP's question